# How to Set Locale In Android Application?

Tags: android, android-intent, locale

I have three activities Login Activity , Complaint Activity and Customer Details Activity.

**A) Login Activity** : The Login activity orientation is Portrait

**B) Complaint Activity** : The Complaint activity orientation is Landscape

**C) Customer Details Activity** : The Customer Details Activity orientation is Portrait

the flow is A => B => C

I use two languages in app English and Marathi.

once I selected Marathi language for first Activity(for entire app).
 i.e Login Activity

the Other preceding activity should follow same locale.

but when activity **B) Complaint Activity** start in landscape mode, it change to default locale i.e English.and app continue in English Language.

How should i set The selected locale for entire app even if the activity changes its orientation.

**My Try**

1) Adding

```
android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"
```

in Manifest File for every Activity

2) Passing Language in intent and retrieving other activity and setting up locale

**Login Activity**

```
  Intent i = new Intent(Login_Activity.this, Complaint_List_Activity_2.class);
            i.putExtra("lang",lang );// lang ="language Code"
            startActivity(complaint_list_activity_intent);
            finish();
```

**Complaint Activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_compalint__list__activity_2);
        Intent pre_intent = getIntent();
        lang = pre_intent.getStringExtra("lang");
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = new Locale(lang);
        }
```

Please explain ,where should i write the code to set the locale in Complaint Activity and how

Comment: You should use `updateConfiguration()` like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2900144/6950238) answer.

Comment: But Where In onCreate of Complaint Activity or onStart of Complaint Activity

Comment: Thank You @AndriyOmelchenko for suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onCreate()` of Complaint Activity because it should be changed once.